# How to leave the data in database if edit form field is left empty

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I getting many inputs from a user in create a form(>50 fields) where I would like to edit those details in edit form.

I have made all the fields nullable so that while editing, the fields are left alone,

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $engineers = Engineers::findOrFail($id);
     $engineers->input1 = $request->input('input1');
     $engineers->input2 = $request->input('input2');
     $engineers->input3 = $request->input('input3');
     $engineers->input4 = $request->input('input4');
     $engineers->save();
}
```

When I try to edit input2 leaving everything blank, all the other fields are blank in the database.

Another option I found out was

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $engineers = Engineers::findOrFail($id);
    if($request->input('input1')){
        $engineers->input1 = $request->input('input1');
    }
    if($request->input('input2')){
        $engineers->input2 = $request->input('input2');
    } 
    if($request->input('input2')){
        $engineers->input2 = $request->input('input2');
    }
     if($request->input('input2')){
        $engineers->input2 = $request->input('input2');
    }

    $engineers->save();
}
```

By doing the above, The corresponding record changes and all the other fields are left intact.

I also noticed that an empty edit form can be submitted.

Are there any other better approach to this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using input array?

Comment: @SaadSuri  Never knew something like this existed. Learning now!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the input before filling the entry e.g.:

```
$engineers = Engineers::findOrFail($id);
$engineers->fill(array_filter($request->all()))->save();
```

This will remove all **falsy** entries i.e. `null` but also `0` and `''`

If you want to strictly remove nulls then you can do :

```
$engineers = Engineers::findOrFail($id);
$engineers->fill(array_filter($request->all(), function ($value) { 
        return $value !== null; 
}))->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

`filled` method of `$request` is used in this case.

```
if($request->filled('name')){
  //if name is present in request object and not empty.
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, this step looks short as well,

```
$engineers = Engineers::findOrFail($id);
$engineers->fill($request->all())->save();
```